# Desing pattern for looping with context dependant output

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a problem and I would like to know if there is a known pattern to apply. I was thinking about the visitor but I am not sure. The problem is the following: let's say I have a queue of boxes that can be in different colors.

```
public class Box{
   public color;
   public Box(String color){
       this.color= color;
   }
   public print(boolean afterGreen){

         System.out.print("\n color is "+color);
         if (afterGreen)
            System.out.print("and goes after a green box");

   }
}
```

Then I have the queue of colors

```
List<Box> queue = new ArrayList<Box>;
queue.add(new Box("red"));
queue.add(new Box("green"));
queue.add(new Box("blue"));
queue.add(new Box("green"));
queue.add(new Box("yellow"));
```

Then I want to print

```
boolean afterGreen = false;
for(Box box : queue){
    box.print(afterGreen);
    afterGreen = "green".equals(box.color);
}
```

As you see, the method print() needs context information. So I calculate it inside the loop and I pass it as a paramenter to the print() method.

Is there a better way to do this, so that I don't have to it inside the loop? Is there a design pattern that solves this?

Comment: The guy responsible for printing "and goes after green box" should be in the guy iterating over the list because he has that information. He knows about the queue.

Comment: Your example isn't coherent. Your Box acts on some information, that only the caller has. Why not let the caller sort the list as he wishes and then just print it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
class Box {
    private String color;

    public Box(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void printAfter(Box previousBox) {
        System.out.print("\n color is " + color);

        if (previousBox != null && previousBox.color.equals("green")) {
            System.out.print("and goes after a green box");
        }
    }
}

Box previousBox;
for(Box box : queue){
    box.printAfter(previousBox);
    previousBox = box;
}
```

The decision about printing after green color is contained within Box object.

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking at implementing something like this.

```
boolean wasGreen = false;
for(Box box : queue) {
    box.print();
    if(wasGreen) {
        System.out.print("and goes after a green box");
    }
    wasGreen = "green".equals(box.color);
}
```